# Difference in conditions /test

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, test

Lets say i have to test if file contains a string "mail" , what is the difference between

```
if grep -q "mail" "file"; then ...


if [ $( grep -l "mail" "file") ]; then ...

[ grep -l "mail" "file" ] && ..
```

Are there any differences in these or are they globaly the same ( like they would result in the same outcome with any condition inside or command)

Comment: First will succeed if return code is 0, second will succeed if there is any output from the command and the last should break and say too many args.

Answer (score 1):

```
if command; then ...
```

evaluates the exit status of `command`. 0 is success (evaluates the condition as true).

First of all: `[` is (almost) identical with `test`, hence it expects the `command` string to comply with its syntax.

```
if [ $(command) ]; then ...
```

evaluates the string containing the output of `command`. In most cases it will not work - see the example below.

```
[ command ] && ..
```

`grep -l "mail" "file"` will be interpreted like this:

- `grep` - a string
- `-l` - unary operator returning the length of the following string
- `"mail"` - a string, will be passed as an argument to the `-l` operator
- `"file"` - a string

Depending on implementation you will get slightly different errors, because the above is asking `[` to evaluate a sequence consisting of a string, a number and another string, without any operators. By default `[` (as well as `test`) is a shell built-in, you can compare the error messages with the standalone binary (usually `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[`).